# Protected Custom Setting not available in lightning Component

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have created a package where I am using some protected custom setting to store credentials etc. I don't want admins to change or see any information from UI so I have created a lighting component to enable change to some fields.

When testing the app in packaging org everything is working as expected but I am getting below error in subscriber org where the app is deployed/installed. .

```
org.auraframework.throwable.quickfix.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid 
definition for <namespace>:<namespace>__<Custom_Settings__c>: null
```

Comment: The custom setting is added to the package and also i am using post install script to populate the values which didn't throw any exception. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like a know issue which is fixed by salesforce. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eqGkQAI

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by using wrapper classes. somehow the salesforce known issue is not fixed.